# How can I solve the SEO problem of the following site which is based on nuxt.js 2 and Laravel 8? (https://darkob.co.ir)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, seo, single-page-application

In this project, for the SEO part of the site, we used the facilities provided by nuxt.js [that is, the property head()] to make the `title` and `meta description` of all the pages dynamic.

If we take the inspect Elements from each page of the website, we can see that it has its own `title` and `meta description`, but when we take the view page source (ctrl + U) from a page, it shows the `title` and `meta description` set in the nuxt.config.js file and does not change dynamically.

Or when we visit common SEO checker sites on the web to get information from each website page in the field of SEO; The address of each page we enter (for example, when we enter the https://darkob.co.ir/trademark address), instead of returning the `title` and `meta description` specific to this page, it returns the `title` and `meta description` that are in the nuxt.config..js file set.

I wanted to ask what is the problem? or How can I solve this problem?

An example of the code that I wrote in the script section of the `trademark.vue` page:

```
  head() {
    return {
      title: '...',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: `description`,
          name: 'description',
          content: '...'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Thank you